# How do I install mono develop for Raspbian 11?

Tags: raspbian, monodevelop

Are there any plans to support Raspbian version 11 (bullseye) for the Pi Zero 2 W installs of monodevelop. mono-complete seems to be supported, but not the IDE.

Comment: This is not the right place for such questions, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b